# Need some precisions to randomise in Python

Tags: python, random

I've managed to write the small code but my skills are very poor (though i'm doing my best)

I want to print images dowloaded from a camera. But though the camera will shoot an image every 30 seconds, I want to print images in a randomised lapse of time (between 3 and 10 minutes)

Could someone help me ? Thanks very much

Here is the code I've done so far.

```
monRep = "***/folder1"
import os, mimetypes, random, glob
while True:
    fpaths = []
    for fname in os.listdir(monRep):
        fpath = os.path.join(monRep, fname)
        if os.path.isfile(fpath):
            mt = mimetypes.guess_type(fpath)[0]
            ext = os.path.splitext(fpath)[1]
            if mt: mt = mt.split('/')[0].lower()
            else: mt = False
            #if ext.lower() in ('.bmp','.pict', '.JPG', '.jpg', '.pdf'): mt = 'image'
            if mt in ('image',): fpaths.append(fpath)

    for fpath in fpaths:
        newpath = fpath.replace('***/Folder1/','***/Folder2/')
        os.rename(fpath,newpath)
        command = "lpr "+newpath
        print (command)
        os.system(command)

    import time
    time.sleep (1)

    directory='***/Folder2/'
    os.chdir(directory)
    files=glob.glob('*.JPG')
    for filename in files:
        os.unlink(filename)
```

Comment: What do you mean by print? Print the filename, show the image in a image processor or send it to a printer?

Comment: Sorry : sent it to a printer Thanks

Comment: Ok, so what is not working now in your script?

Comment: I don't want to print all the images dowloaded in Folder1 but choose one in a random way and print it in a lapse of time between 3 and 10 minutes. Lapse of time also choosen in a random way (from 3 to 10)

Answer (score 0):

Run this an another script because it should be independent of your importing code:

```
import glob
import random
import time

while True:
    directory='***/Folder1/'
    files = glob.glob('*.JPG') #get all jpg files in your dir
    selected_file = random.choice(files) #selects a random entry in 'files'
    #print selected file
    sleeptime = random.randint(3*60, 11*60) #selects random number between 3 and 11 min (in sec)
    time.sleep(sleeptime) #and sleep for that time
```

Comment: Rickie

I want to thank you very much... I'm gonna try this asap

One question the idea is to run the two codes separatly but at the same time, am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, you run the importer in one script, and this in another. Otherwise the sleep in this code is causing your import job to halt for that time.

Comment: I was thinking that the previous script is supposed to send every image directly to the printer... Should I increase the sleeping time in order to let the 2nd script works ?